# Error: While importing 'wsgi', an ImportError was raised. Python Flask Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, wsgi, pipenv

I am building a backend using Python and Flask, everything worked fine, but after some updates on the Pipfile (updated some packages) I got this error when I try to run the app (flask run):

**Error: While importing 'wsgi', an ImportError was raised.**

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.5
- Flask 2.0.2
- pipenv 2020.8.13
- pip 21.2.4

Also, I tried with pyenv 1.2.21

I tried to run the backend in VSC but got the same error.
Also, I tried to remove the interpreter and set it up again, remove Pipfile.lock, and pipenv install again...
I have googled but found nothing about this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try `python wsgi.py` and check output, maybe you should install additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file `__init__.py` to the application directory